# error C3861: 'cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK': identifier not found

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to run opencv based Lucas-kande algorithm in Visual studio 2012 .
I am using the code from this link :
    http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut9.html#Step 1

I did all require setting in visual studio for opencv ,but still I am getting below error :

```
error C3861: 'cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK': identifier not found
```

OPENCV Version: 3.0

Visual studion:2012

Platform:x64

Comment: The tutorial is from *2009*, and seems to be from before OpenCV 2.0. OpenCV has changed a lot since then, and the opencv site returns no hits for that identifier.

Comment: Can you please give me link to the opencv  lucas Kande code